# Is it possible to know what widget user stay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

there is one question to prevents me from implementing the logic of my App.

there is Widget A and Widget Other(which means is non-widget A).

is there possible to know the user is staying in widget A or other widgets.

I want to implement the flow like the user has visited widget A and he/she go to other widgets, in these other widgets there will be a popup dialog to be shown after the 10 seconds timer is triggered.

but there are 3 problems:

1. how do I know the user is visiting other widgets after she/he has visited widget A.
2. how do I know when she/he was leaving widget A(for trigger purpose).
3. how do I trigger the flow on other widgets, since there have so many other widgets.

thanks

Comment: You can use the default life cycle methods provided in [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7) or use some package like [focus_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector) and keep track of it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried changing any attributes between the widgets? For example, make one widget's color to be pink and another widget's color green. How many widgets (roughly) do you have that are similar?

Comment: @James666      no I just want to pop up the dialog in other widgets after the user has visited widget A.  it seems difficult because I need to trigger the dialog in all non-widget A. there will be a problem if I popup the dialog in widget A when the user visiting other widgets?